# How to implement GDate in Java

Tags: java

I am new to jave from c++. I am wondering how to use Gdate as specified at http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/GDate.html

Can anyone give a simple example how to calculate the time period between two date using Gdate? or maybe just current date...

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the API spec it seems that the following code should give you the time period in milliseconds

```
public long dateDiffInMillis (final GDate date1, final GDate date2) {
    return date1.getCalendar ().getTimeInMillis () - date2.getCalendar ().getTimeInMillis ();
}
```

Comment: do i need to import anything?

Comment: Nothing except the `org.apache.xmlbeans.GDate`

Comment: so i need to have import org.apache.xmlbeans.GDate at the beginning at the code?

Comment: i tried import org.apache.xmlbeans.GDate, but it is not working