# Use GDate to calculate period between dates

Tags: java, date, xmlbeans

I am new to java and am wondering how to use `GDate` as specified at the [JavaDocs](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/GDate.html).

- Can anyone give a simple example how to calculate the time period between two date using `GDate`?

Comment: It would probably help to "learn" Java first

Comment: I see you've asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327167/how-to-implement-gdate-in-java) once... For your comment question, Apache is not a standard toolkit, so you have to copy the whole jar, into your project - then you can import you desired classes.

Comment: I suggest you do a Hello World in Java tutorial first, and then maybe read Java for dummies! Your question is not about GDate but about simple Java usage... do your research, follow tutorials and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..do I need to import anythig at the start of the program?

Yes, `org.apache.xmlbeans.GDate`

> How to declare an object?

```
GDate gDate = new GDate(/* See JavaDocs for constructors */);
```

See [JavaDocs for constructors](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/GDate.html#constructor_summary).